# Easiest way to update mysql table via html form

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, forms

I need to update values in a mysql table. This has to be checked by hand and I cannot give the person permission to phpmyadmin.

So I want to create a html table which displays the mysql table. It has more columns but for simplicity let's say we have:

```
 name   age   gender
 jake    23     M
 jenny   45     M
 bob     12     M
```

Now I want to display this on an html page in a table or something so this aligns nicely and we can go through the data and i.e. change the gender of Jenny from M to F. 
I either want one of 2 things:

1) whenever a value in a row is changed make an Ajax request to the server with all variables of that row so a mysql update can be done.

2) the entire table will be put in a form and at the bottom of the page is a submit button which sends all the data in a way that it can be put in a dictionary or dataframe in Python to loop over all the rows so the mysql table can be updated. (I asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858032/form-table-as-dictionary-input-python) but didn't receive any answers)

I now tried this but it doesn't call the function:

```
 In the header of html:


$('.formclass').change(function() {
    console.log("testing");

});
```

I then do a request to the server to fill the table the python code is:

```
table1 = {mysql query data}

data = """

    <table border = 5 bordercolor = red align = center>
"""

for i,row in table1.iterrows():

    sstr = """
        <tr>
        <form action="/test.py" class='formclass'>
        <td><input type="text" name="id" value="{0}" readonly/></td>
        <td>name: {1} </td>
        <td colspan = 4><input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" checked>Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">Female</td>
        </form>
        </tr>
    """.format(row['id'],row['name'])

    data = data + sstr

data = data + """</table>"""

print(data)
```

However it doesn't even log in the console. And then I also need the data from the row still.

What I see in the html is that the form elements are put in another place so the table cells are not in the form anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Views](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) as a best practice for SELECT.

Comment: Views are used for SELECT not UPDATE.